# R: regular expression lookaround(s) to grab whats between two patterns

Tags: regex, r

I have a vector with strings like:

```
x <-c('kjsdf_class-X1(z)20_sample-318TT1X.3','kjjwer_class-Z3(z)29_sample-318TT2X.4')
```

I wanted to use regular expressions to get what is between substrings 'class-' and '_sample' (such as 'X1(z)20' and 'Z3(z)29' in `x`), and thought the lookaround regex ((?=...), (?!...),... and so) would do it. Cannot get it to work though!

Sorry if this is similar to other SO questions eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425071/regular-expression-lookaround) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834872/r-regular-expression-lookbehind)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit different then what you had in mind, but it will do the job.

```
gsub("(.*class-)|(.)|(_sample.*)", "\\2", x)
```

The logic is the following, you have 3 "sets" of strings:

1) characters `.*` ending in `class-`

2) characters `.`

3) Characters starting with `_sample` and characters afterwords `.*`

From those you want to keep the second "set" `\\2`.

Or another maybe easier to understand:

```
gsub("(.*class-)|(_sample.*)", "", x)
```

Take any number of characters that end in `class-` and the string `_sample` followed by any number of characters, and substitute them with the `NULL` character `""`

Comment: Sure it does (I will have to understand lookaround another day then). Could you explain briefly the regex pattern ?

Answer (score 1):

We could use `str_extract_all` from `library(stringr)`

```
 library(stringr)
 unlist(str_extract_all(x, '(?<=class-)[^_]+(?=_sample)'))
 #[1] "X1(z)20" "Z3(z)29"
```

This should also work if there are multiple instances of the pattern within a string

```
 x1 <- paste(x, x)
 str_extract_all(x1, '(?<=class-)[^_]+(?=_sample)')
 #[[1]]
 #[1] "X1(z)20" "X1(z)20"

 #[[2]]
 #[1] "Z3(z)29" "Z3(z)29"
```

Basically, we are matching the characters that are between the two lookarounds (`(?<=class-)` and `(?=_sample)`).  We extract characters that is not a `_` (based on the example) preceded by `class-` and succeded by `_sample`.

Answer (score 0):

```
gsub('.*-([^-]+)_.*','\\1',x)
[1] "X1(z)20" "Z3(z)29"
```

Comment: This answer could really do with a more detailed explanation to go with it.